# Installation of Meteor on an OpenShift account

Tags: meteor, installation, openshift

I have tried to install meteor on my new OpenShift Package. I finally managed to get ssh-access, but the installation fails with these lines:

`[nodejs-afnm.rhcloud.com 5417xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx343f]\> curl https://install.meteor.com | sh`

`% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  4506    0  4506    0     0  12817      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 97956
mkdir: cannot create directory /var/lib/openshift/5417xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx343f//.meteor-install-tmp: Permission denied
Installation failed.
[nodejs-afnm.rhcloud.com 5417xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx343f]\>`

It is a free OpenShift account. Why does it say 'Permission denied' when vreating a directory? Am I in the wrong directory?

Answer (score 0):

You can't install meteor like that, you don't have access to write to your home directory, try following this blog article about how to setup meteor on your openshift account: https://www.openshift.com/blogs/cloudy-with-a-chance-of-meteorjs

Comment: Hello developercorey, you are right.
I already tried the installation described in the link you mentioned. Unfortunately without success.
Another error message about the url/dns appeared... anyway, maybe i try to contact openshift directly.